# What are these pests? Harmful? How to get rid of?

Tags: vegetables, soil, pests, raised-beds

I recently decided to have a vegetable and herb garden and put in raised planters along my house. Two of the 4 raised gardens have a TON of these tiny pests in the soil. Interestingly enough they don’t seem to be on the plants, just in the soil. I tried neem oil and an insecticidal soap for organic gardening and no such luck. Attaching a picture I got of them - they’re tiny, this is zoomed in and they’re next to a gnat. I also have a video of them (https://youtu.be/3WZ-HC0ogSU). Any ideas what they are, how to get rid of them and if they’re harmful?
[image]

Comment: There's lots of things live in the soil and are not a pest. Are there any issues with plants?